# How primary memory is organised in a microcontroller?

Tags: c, memory, microcontroller, memory-address

My query is :How the memory is organized and managed in the microcontroller?
(It doesn't have any OS i.e no presence of MMU).

I am working over zynq 7000 (ZC702) FPGA,It has seperate arm core and seperate DDR memory connected together with axi interconnects.

I wrote 11 1111 1111 in decimal to DDR(10 1's),it is giving me same after reading.
when i write 111 1111 1111 in decimal to DDR(11 1's),it gives me -1.

here the whole physical memory is consumed.This will not be the case when i use any microcontroller.
Who will manage the memory in microcontroller?

Comment: Please note that MMU and OS are distinguished concepts. You may have one without the other.

Comment: SoC and microcontroller are different term nowadays. Your question is very unclear. There is neiter a single SoC type, nor a single microcontroller. And FPGA based SoCs are even more flexible. You should learn more about the basics, you seem very confused (no offence).

Comment: Microcontrollers differes alot, you have to read their manuals. I mean since you don't have an OS to take care of the different architectures, you have to do it yourself. See if the manufacturer provides some dev kits.

Comment: @AUS :you mean on micro controllers it can be done at manufacturer level.can i say,In ARM startup.s will do the same????

Comment: Don't know. But when I worked on an embedded system (ARM) I got the toolchain from the manufacturer. Then I was able to correctly cross compile an OS for it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay that is a cortex-A9, in no way shape or form is that a microcontroller.

When you read the arm documentation for that architecture you will find the mmu in there.  It as expected is part of the Cortex-A core.

Who/how/when is the ddr initialized?  Someone has to initialize it before you can write to it and read it back.  10 ones in decimal fits in a 32 bit write/read, 11 ones, takes 33 bits, what size write/read did you use?  How much ddr do you have?   I suspect you are not ready to be talking to ddr

There is 256K of on chip ram, maybe you should mess with that first.

All of this is in the zilinx and arm documentation.  Experienced bootloader developers can take months to get DDR initialized, how/who/when was that done, do you have dram tests to confirm that it is up and working if you werent the one to initialize it?  Has zilinx provided routines for that (how is your ddr initialized, who did it (your code, some code before yours, logic, etc) and when was it done, before your code ran?).  Maybe it is your job to initialize.

the MMU you just read the arm docs as with everything about that core.  Then work with the xilinx docs for more, and then of course who did the rest of the fpga design to connect the arm core to the dram?  what address space are they using, what decoding, what alignments do they support, what axi transfers are supported, etc?  That is not something anyone here could do you have to talk to the fpga logic designers for your specific design.

If you have no operating system then you are running bare metal.  You the programmer are responsible for memory management.  You dont need the mmu necessarily, sometimes it helps sometimes it just adds more work.  Depends completely on your programming task and overall design of the software and system.  The mmu is hardware, an operating system is software that runs on hardware.  One thing might use the other but they are in no way tied to each other any more than the interrupt controller or dram controller or uart, etc are tied to the operating system.  The operating system or other software may use that hardware, but you can use them with other software as well.